# FireDac FdQuery com MySql Transaction.commit e rollback nao funciona

Tags: delphi, transações, firedac, rollback

### Estou fazendo um teste com FdConnection e FdQuery e banco de dados MySql. Na minha tabela teste existe apenas um campo chamado chave com primary key.
Executando comando abaixo, rollback nao funciona.

Relacionar o item

```
  FdConnection1.TxOptions.AutoCommit:=false;
  FdConnection1.Connected:=true;
  try
    FdConnection1.StartTransaction;
    FdQuery1.SQL.Text:=('insert into teste (chave) values (:chave)');
    FdQuery1.ExecSQL('',['01']);
    FdQuery1.ExecSQL('',['01']);
    FDConnection1.Commit;
  except
    FDConnection1.Rollback;
    showMessage('Erro');
  end;
```

---

Executando este comando mostra mensagem "erro", mas na tabela inseriu um registro. Deveria estar vazia, certo? Se alguem puder ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se sua tabela suporta transações, se este for o caso faça um teste usando o "Start Transaction" , "Commit" e "Rollback" no SQL da FdQuery1 mesmo, ao invés de usar o do FdConnection.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente quando uso transação faço essa estrutura e funciona perfeitamente.

Adicionei um `Try exception` para saber o que está acontecendo de fato.

```
  FdConnection1.StartTransaction;
  try
    FdQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    FdQuery1.SQL.Text:=('insert into teste (chave) values (:chave)');
    FdQuery1.ExecSQL('',['01']);
    FdQuery1.ExecSQL('',['01']);
    FDConnection1.Commit;
  except on E : Exception do
    begin
      FDConnection1.Rollback;
      ShowMessage('Classe do Erro: '+ E.ClassName +' Mensagem do erro: '+E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```